# Modify scope variable through jQuery callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have the following code snippet:

```
  $scope.addName = (name) ->
    $scope.names.push name
  $(".names").draggable
    helper: "clone"
    revert: true
  $(".name-list").droppable
    accept: ".names"
    activate: ->
      $(@).addClass "bordered"
    deactivate: ->
      $(@).removeClass "bordered"
    drop: (e, ui) ->
      name = ui.draggable.attr "data-names-name"
      $scope.addName name
```

Here, the user drags a name (represented) as a `div` on the name list, and then the dragged name is added to the name array.

The problem is that, the names array remains empty after pushing the new name into it.

Comment: Mixing angular and jquery is generally contraindicated. You should be able to do this with directives (and I'm positive you can do droppable with angular alone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a script executes outside of an angular context, then you need to manually let angular know to trigger a digest cycle and update the views.

In script, you should be able to do the following:

```
drop: (e, ui) ...

$(e).scope().$digest();
```

I noticed that $scope is already available within then drop function. Then the following is better:

```
 $scope.$digest();
```

Comment: $scope.$digest isn't the safe solution as it might throw an error `digest already in progress`, you should strongly reconsider using `$scope.$apply( -> *variables to apply on scope*)`

Comment: That is not quite correct. There is no real difference between $scope.$apply and $scope.$digest, except that $scope.$apply gives you an opportunity to execute code before calling $digest.  Whether you use $apply or $digest has nothing to do with whether one is more likely to throw a 'digest already in progress' error.

Comment: You are WRONG @pixelbits: `Usually, you don't call $digest() directly in controllers or in directives. Instead, you should call $apply() (typically from within a directive), which will force a $digest().` that's directly from angularjs documentation and $scope.$digest is DIRECTLY related to `digest already in progress` error

Comment: Look at the pseudo code for $apply, it is very clear that $apply will evaluate code before calling $digest - which is exactly what I said.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply. You are mis-understanding / mis-interpreting the angular documentation.

Comment: what part of this i'm miss-interpreting `Usually, you don't call $digest() directly in controllers or in directives. Instead, you should call $apply()`

Comment: Can you provide a concrete reference or example that shows me that $apply is preferable over $digest because (as you said) that $digest is unsafe and leads to 'digest already in progress error' but $apply does not?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a $scope.$apply (sorry for not using CofeeScript)

```
..
$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.addName(name);
});
```